# List of arrays in Mathematica

Tags: list-manipulation, object-oriented

How would I declare a list of arrays and treat them as single objects? For example, I may have the Pauli matrices:

$$
\sigma_0 = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}, \sigma_1 = \begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Now I want to create a list, using the above two matrices as elements and then use the list in a for loop. What would be the correct syntax for it?

TIA

Comment: You may want to look at the examples of [`PauliMatrix`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PauliMatrix.html)

Comment: Generate them with a `Table` for example: `matrices=Table[PauliMatrix[i], {i, 0, 5}]`, then if you can,  prefer a `Map` to a `For` loop, for example: `mdets=Map[Det,matrices]` to get determinants, or `m3=Map[MatrixPower[#,3]&, matrices]` to cube all of them.